# Sqlalchemy association proxy and no_autoflush

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out why I need to use a no_autoflush block when inserting data into an association proxy if the association proxy data has been accessed first. An example of this is bellow (using MySQL):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, Column, String, ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, scoped_session

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('{}://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(...))
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

class DomainModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'domains'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    domains_to_servers = relationship("DomainServerModel", back_populates="domain")
    servers = association_proxy('domains_to_servers', 'server',
                                creator=lambda s: DomainServerModel(server=s))


class ServerModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'servers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(128), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    domains_to_servers = relationship("DomainServerModel", back_populates="server")
    domains = association_proxy('domains_to_servers', 'domain',
                                creator=lambda d: DomainServerModel(domain=d))


class DomainServerModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'domains_to_servers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    domain_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('domains.id'), nullable=False)
    server_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('servers.id'), nullable=False)
    server = relationship('ServerModel', back_populates="domains_to_servers")
    domain = relationship('DomainModel', back_populates="domains_to_servers")


def test():
     session = Session()
     with session.no_autoflush:
        s = session.query(ServerModel).filter_by(name='test.com').one()
        print(s.domains)
        d = DomainModel(name='test1.com')
        session.add(d)
        session.commit()
        s.domains.append(d)
        session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session()
    session.add(ServerModel(name='test.com'))
    session.commit()
    test()
```

I'm trying to add a new domain_to_server mapping via the server/domain association proxy. If I don't access the association proxy first, ie remove the print statement in test(), then I can add the domain without needing the session.no_autoflush block. But with the print statement in there, it will fail without the session.no_autoflush block with an IntegrityError, saying that server_id cannot be null in the domains to servers table.

I'm trying to figure out why the no_autoflush block is needed here. I don't see any mention of it in the association_proxy docs. Is this simply the way it is, and all inserts into an association_proxy should to happen in a no_autoflush bock in case it has been accessed prior to the insert?